# stretch TextBlocks inside a Grid in a universal App

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am having a problem in fixing 3 TextBlocks inside a Grid,in a metro App,I used this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137884/let-textbox-stretch-to-fill-width-in-stackpanel)

but I get always a problem in stretching my TextBlocks inside the Grid
this is my code:

```
<ListView  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid  Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Margin="0">
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="images/img1.png"  Margin="0,5"  Stretch="Fill" Width="80"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1"  Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="text1" Text="test1"  Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="text2" Text="test2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="text3" Text="test3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

so please I need your help,to fix that
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit style of ListViewItem and set HorizontalAlignment to Stretch

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                  Value="Stretch" />
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                  Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```